# udev rule generating symlink for USB-device using ATTRS{serial} in link name

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I have a udev rule that generates symlinks for my USB devices in `/dev` according to their serial number (I have multiple otherwise identical devices but need reproducible device endpoints).

Currently I need to add a rule for every new serial number, like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", ATTRS{serial}=="S101", SYMLINK+="ttyS101"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", ATTRS{serial}=="S102", SYMLINK+="ttyS102"
...
```

I'm looking for a way to do this with a single rule, all that is dynamically accessible is `%k`, `%n`, and `%c`, but I found no way to access any other values. Using `PROGRAM=""` might be the way, but how would I access ATTRS from there?

I tried this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", ATTRS{serial}=="S101", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'udevadm info /dev/%k | grep ID_SERIAL_SHORT= | cut -d= -f 2'" SYMLINK+="tty%c"
```

but it looks like `/dev/%k` is not available when the program runs, so that doesn't work either.

Is there any way to use `ATTRS{serial}` for my `SYMLINK+=""`?

Comment: Well written Q, but as this oesn't seem to rely on a programming language, and seems to be linux conf-file magic, seems more appropriate to ask this on [unix.se] or [sf]. (IMHO). Good luck!

Comment: udev rules are a programming language.  They have conditionals and gotos.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using USB serial ports.  It should be easier for you to just access these devices via the symbolic links in `/dev/serial/by-id`.  There is no need to make udev rules.

Answer (score 0):

While looking for a way to setup a stable `ttyACM_DEVMODEL_SERIAL` symlink for a USB device with a CDC interface I found `$attr{file}, %s{file}` in [udev's man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udev.7.html). The `{file}` in question is `serial` for USB devices serial strings. I tested it and it worked as expected for me.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1257", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3511", SYMLINK+="ttyACM_ASI%s{idProduct}_%s{serial}"
```